# Question about the physics of nuclear interactions

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, nuclear-physics, field-theory

I have been reading  [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/2105.11981) paper on nuclear interactions data. It shows plenty of plots of nuclear reaction data as a function of energy (actually, energy scaled by nuclear mass). All these graphs seem to show the same trend. They begin at a certain energy, since these are threshold reactions, then a peak is reached, followed by a small minimum and a region of seemingly constant value.

Take the following graph, showing total nuclear cross sections of He-4 interacting with various nuclei, as an example. [image: example].

The solid lines are model calculations shown with the corresponding measured data. According to the same plot, the interaction probability also grows with increasing the mass of the target.

Perhaps, the constant part might be explained along the lines of the heuristic formula for the capture cross section $\sigma_c(E)$, for a nucleolus of radius $R$ and Coulomb barrier of height $V_b$
$$
\sigma_c(E) =
    \begin{cases}
      & \pi R^2 \left[1-\frac{V_b(R)}{E}\right] &,  E>V_b(R) \\
      & 0                                       &,  E<V_b(R) \\
    \end{cases}  
$$

According to the above formula, $\sigma_c(E)$ clearly reaches a constant value in the limit $E \gg V_b(E)$.

I would really appreciate if someone would explain the shape of these cross sections (the peak, the minimum and the constant part) and/or point to a good book on the subject.
Thank you